# php zip-ing multiple file prompt damage file

Tags: php, file, zip

Just now I have created a zip generation script, script works fine while zipping one file or two three files but when I try to download whole directory in zip which contain more then 30 files total of 166MB, scripts generates the zip of 2KB but prompt archive is unknown format or damaged

```
<?php
$error = ""; //error holder

$post = $_POST; 
$file = $_GET['file'];

//die($file);
$file_folder = $_GET['file']; // folder to load files
if(extension_loaded('zip'))
{ 
// Checking ZIP extension is available

// Checking files are selected
$zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name


if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
{ 
 // Opening zip file to load files
$error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}

if (is_dir($file)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($file)) {
        while (($filename = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if(!is_dir($file . $filename)){
                $zip->addFile($file . $filename); // Adding files into zip

            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
} else {
    if(file_exists($file)){
        $zip->addFile($file); // Adding files into zip
    } else {
        $error = "* File not found";
    }
}
$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name))
{
// push to download the zip
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
readfile($zip_name);
// remove zip file is exists in temp path
unlink($zip_name);
}


}
else
$error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension";

if($error!=''){
    header("Location: index.php?cat=62&msg=Download currently not available, sorry for inconvenience.");
}
?>
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$error = ""; //error holder

$post = $_POST; 
$file = $_GET['file'];

//die($file);
$file_folder = $_GET['file']; // folder to load files
if(extension_loaded('zip'))
{ 
// Checking ZIP extension is available

// Checking files are selected
$zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name


if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
{ 
 // Opening zip file to load files
$error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}

if (is_dir($file)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($file)) {
        while (($filename = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if(!is_dir($file . $filename)){
                $zip->addFile($file . $filename); // Adding files into zip

            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
} else {
    if(file_exists($file)){
        $zip->addFile($file); // Adding files into zip
    } else {
        $error = "* File not found";
    }
}
$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name))
{
    // push to download the zip
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    $zip_file = file_get_contents($zip_name);
    print $zip_file;
    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
    unlink($zip_name);
}


}
else
$error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension";

if($error!=''){
    header("Location: index.php?cat=62&msg=Download currently not available, sorry for inconvenience.");
}
?>
```

What I did is replaced 'readfile' with this:

```
    $zip_file = file_get_contents($zip_name);
    print $zip_file;
```

I don't know what is causing the corruption to the zip.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Jey the code works now but what is this what it has to do with the bug, I have searched for the difference b/w file_get_contents and readfile and readfile seems to have better results then file_get_contents.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this is not live on a production server as its pretty unsafe to allow someone to set a path to be zipped but if not...

Without debugging your code, try something like (updated to handle filesize over phps memory limit)

```
<?php
//set path
$path = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : null;

//check exists
if($path != null && file_exists($path)){
    //out zip name
    $zip_out = time().".zip";
    //zip it or return error
    if(Zippit::zipDir($path, $zip_out) === false){
        exit(header("Location: ./index.php?cat=62&msg=*+You+dont+have+ZIP+extension"));
    }

    // push to download the zip
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($zip_out).'"');
    header('Content-Length: '.sprintf("%u", filesize($zip_out)));
    readfile($zip_out);
    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
    unlink($zip_out);
    exit();
}else{
    exit(header("Location: ./index.php?cat=62&msg=*+File+not+Found"));
}

/**
 * Zippit
 * usage: Zippit::zipDir($path, $zip_out);
 */
class Zippit {
    /**
     * Add files and sub-directories in a folder to zip file.
     * @param string $folder
     * @param ZipArchive $zipFile
     * @param int $exclusiveLength Number of text to be exclusived from the file path.
     */
    private static function folderToZip($folder, &$zipFile, $exclusiveLength) {
        $handle = opendir($folder);
        while (false !== $f = readdir($handle)) {
            if ($f != '.' && $f != '..') {
                $filePath = $folder."/".$f;
                // Remove prefix from file path before add to zip.
                $localPath = substr($filePath, $exclusiveLength);
                if (is_file($filePath)) {
                    $zipFile->addFile($filePath, $localPath);
                } elseif (is_dir($filePath)) {
                    // Add sub-directory.
                    $zipFile->addEmptyDir($localPath);
                    self::folderToZip($filePath, $zipFile, $exclusiveLength);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    /**
     * Zip a folder (include itself).
     *   Usage:
     *   Zippit::zipDir('/path/to/sourceDir', '/path/to/out.zip');
     *
     * @param string $sourcePath Path of directory to be zip.
     * @param string $outZipPath Path of output zip file.
     */
    public static function zipDir($sourcePath, $outZipPath)
    {
        $pathInfo   = pathInfo($sourcePath);
        $parentPath = $pathInfo['dirname'];
        $dirName    = $pathInfo['basename'];

        $z = new ZipArchive();
        if (!$z->open($outZipPath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
            return false;
        }
        $z->addEmptyDir($dirName);
        self::folderToZip($sourcePath, $z, strlen($parentPath."/"));
        $z->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence, your code working fine for single file but throws a blank page for mutliple ( no zip file generated )

Comment: Your need enough memory to handle any files you add to the zip, enable error_reporting

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I am also finding what is making this problem otherwise all file zip will be uploaded manually for download.
This script generated a zip file of 1.45KB which prompt "unknown format or damaged", on single file it goes into infinite echo-ing warning about opendir is not a directory, readdir expect parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: I checked it on local and I have no issue of memory on local machine.

Comment: It works for me :) only suggestion I can make is to rename the zip file to .txt and open it in a txt editor to see if there are php errors, as the zip is 1.45KB so what is the 1.45KB contained. **Also check your php error log on your server**.  Also there is no path checking in the example so check the path is correct that your passing to `?path=` and that PHP has access to the path your trying to zip. bit of basic debugging...